# How to introduce the ondelete cascade in hibernate with annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I am new to hibernate. I have requirement to introduce the delete functionality in hibernate with annotation. ie once we delete the parent, it needs to delete child records ie i need to introduce the ondelete cascade feature. Could you please help how to introduce this feature. please find below is java/entity code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "atfLabel", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"key_", "module_id"}))
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Label {
    private long id;
    private ModuleImpl module;
    private String key;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)   
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="module_id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    public ModuleImpl getModule() {
        return module;
    }
    public void setModule(ModuleImpl module) {
        this.module = module;
    }

    @Column(name="key_", length=160)
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }   
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "atfModule")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ModuleImpl implements Module {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="module")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE)
    private List<Label> label;

    @Override
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    @Column(length=200, unique=true, nullable=false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    @Column(length=2000)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDescription(String desc) {
        this.description=desc;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "atfLabelText",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "label_id", "tenant_id", "locale" }))
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LabelText {
    private long id;
    private Label label;
    private TenantImpl tenant;
    private String locale;
    private String text;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "label_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    public Label getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public String getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id", nullable = true, updatable = false)
    public TenantImpl getTenant() {
        return tenant;
    }

    @Column(length = 1500)
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setLabel(Label label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public void setLocale(String locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public void setTenant(TenantImpl tenant) {
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

could you please help me how to do delete functionality and ondelete cascade future.
Thanks
Vijaya Kumar

Answer (score 1):

When you use `CascadeType.DELETE`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="module")
@Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE)
private List<Label> label;
```

It tells Hibernate to navigate the `label` association and delete persistent instances when an object of `ModuleImpl` is passed to delete().

Again, if you want to delete any `Label` persistence instance when it is removed from the `label` association, you should go with `all-delete-orphan`:

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "module")
private List<Label> label;
```

With `all-delete-orphan`,any newly instantiated `Label` becomes persistent if the `Label` is referenced by a persistent `Module`. Any persistent `Label` will be deleted if it’s referenced by an `Module` when the `Module` is deleted. And also any persistent `Label` will be deleted if it’s removed from the `label` collection of a persistent `Module`.

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
  at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
  at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
  at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
  at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
  at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:189)

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lportal`.`atflabeltext`, CONSTRAINT `FKA6C78EE9D4FD6A4` FOREIGN KEY (`label_id`) REFERENCES `atflabel` (`id`))
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1257)

Comment: Let me guess what you want to achieve.Correct me if I am wrong. You want to create and persist an instance of `Module` with a set of `labels`. And when you `delete` a persistence instance of `Module`, the associated `labels` should also be deleted along with the module. If this is what you want, you need to go with `all-delete-orphan`. With this, you don't need to save your `labels` separately. Define an `addLabel` method in your `ModuleImpl` class: `public void addLabel(Label label){ label.setModule(this);labels.add(label)}` and add labels to module using this before passing it to `save`.